# MATLAB sub2ind using vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, algebra

Suppose I have a matrix A

```
A = magic(5)

17    24     1     8    15
23     5     7    14    16
 4     6    13    20    22
10    12    19    21     3
11    18    25     2     9
```

Now I select a block of this matrix using

```
A(1:2, 1:2)

17    24
23     5
```

Now I need the linear index given by (1:2, 1;2) which are (1 2 6 7). Using sub2ind:

```
sub2ind(size(A),[1:2], [1:2])
```

But this command returns just (1 7) how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you want to select `A(1:2,2:3)`:

```
% Row and column indexes
rind = 1:2;
cind = 2:3;

pos  = bsxfun(@plus,rind', size(A,2)*(cind-1));

pos =
     6    11
     7    12
```

You might want to reshape it into a column vector `pos(:)`, or in one line with a call to `reshape()`.

Comment: Unfortunately your code doesn't work if the matrix is not square.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the 4 subscripts: `[1 1]`, `[2 1]`, `[1 2]` and `[2 2]`.

```
>> sub2ind(size(A),[1 2 1 2], [1 1 2 2])

ans =

     1     2     6     7
```

Comment: Ok.. But I have only (1:2, 1;2). What you have written is my point of arrival.

Comment: So you want to transform `[1:2], [1:2]` to `[1 2 1 2], [1 1 2 2]`?

Comment: Exactly :) Suppose I have x and y and in my program I use them for indexing.