# MATLAB: Matrix containing values of another matrix at specific indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-guide, indices

I need help solving an indexing problem. The assigned problem states: Two matrices (x and y) give the coordinates to form matrix B from matrix A. Produce the matrix B which contains the values of A at the given coordinates in x and y. 
For instance:

```
x = [1 1 1; 2 2 1]
y = [1 2 1; 3 2 4]
%This would read as (1,1),(1,2),(1,1),(2,3),(2,2),(1,4)
% Given matrix: 
A = [6 7 8 9; 10 11 12 13];
%This would give us this answer for B (using the coordinate scheme above): 
B=[6 7 6; 12 11 9];
```

I'm guessing I need to use the `find` function in conjunction with a `sub2ind` function, but I'm not 100% sure how to translate that into working code. The only thing I can think of would be to do something like this:

```
B=((x(1),(y(1)), (x(2),y(2)).......
```

But that would only work for the defined matrix above, not a randomly generated matrix. I tried looking for a similar problem on the site, but I couldn't find one. Your help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Try using a loop. Sometimes the simplest approach is the best.

Comment: You're right, `sub2ind` would be helpful here, as well `reshape` if you like. You don't need a loop -this can be done on one line. Read about [linear indexing here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85511) to see if you can figure out what to do wit the output from `ind2sub`.

Comment: This has been answered in many questions, _e.g_: [Selecting elements from an array in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023997/), [Changing multiple elements (of known coordinates) of a matrix without a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12294232), [MATLAB sub2ind using vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530668), and many more...

Comment: possible duplicate of [MATLAB sub2ind using vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530668/matlab-sub2ind-using-vectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it for randomly generated matrices, because you have to ensure that matrix `A` has lines and columns as required from the values of `x` and `y`.

In this case, you can write:

```
for i=1:length(x(:))
   B(i)=A(x(i),y(i));
end
B=reshape(B,size(x));
```

Comment: I keep getting an error when I implement your code: "To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change." and "Error in B=reshape(B,size(x)) ". Here is what I put in the script, it isn't working:x = [1 1 1; 2 2 1]
y = [1 2 1; 3 2 4]
A = [6 7 8 9; 10 11 12 13]
for i=1:length(x(:))
   B(i)=A(x(i),y(i));
   
end
B=reshape(B,size(x))

Comment: I copied your code, and get B=[6 7 6; 12 11 9]. I don't know what the problem... what do you get for `size(B)`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just retried after clearing `clear,clc` the command window, and it worked! I got the correct matrix. Thank you for your assistance! :D